# How to change the type of field in an array of sub-documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents, each of which possesses an array of subdocuments (ranging from 1-10,000 objects). In a small portion of these documents, a field in the arrayed sub-documents has been set to a string instead of an integer and I need to convert these values to an Integer

Here is a structural sample. Note that the DB Admin built the database and collection names with a '.' notation which has complicated some of my work thus far:

```
Collection Name: "employee.roster"
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5f11d4c28663f32e940696e0"),
  "PdfId" : NumberInt(100),
  "Staff" : [
    {
      "StaffId" : NumberInt(1),
      "StaffName" : "John Doe"
    },
    {
      "StaffId" : NumberInt(2),
      "StaffName" : "John Smith"
    },
    {
      "StaffId" : "3",
      "StaffName" : "John Jones"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5f11d4c28663f32e940696e1"),
  "PdfId" : NumberInt(110),
  "Staff" : [
    {
      "StaffId" : "4",
      "StaffName" : "Bob Loblaw"
    },
    {
      "StaffId" : NumberInt(5),
      "StaffName" : "Edward Nigma"
    },
    {
      "StaffId" : "6",
      "StaffName" : "Hugh Mongus"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried a variety of methods without success. Based on other posts, I thought something like this should work but I've generated nothing but errors:

```
db.getCollection("staff.roster").update(
  {},
  [{ $set: { "Staff.$[elem].StaffId": { $toInt: "$Staff.$[elem].StaffId" } } }],
  { "arrayFilters": [{ "elem.StaffId": { $type: 2 } } ], "multi": true }
)

ERROR MESSAGE:
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 9,
        "errmsg" : "arrayFilters may not be specified for pipeline-syle updates"
    }
})
```

I've also tried this but I believe my notation is wrong because of the sub-documents:

```
db.getCollection("staff.roster").find( { "Staff.StaffId" : { $type : 2 } } ).forEach( function (x) {   
  x."Staff.StaffId" = new NumberInt(x."Staff.StaffId");
  db.getCollection("staff.roster").save(x);
});
```

My output should look like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5f11d4c28663f32e940696e0"),
  "PdfId" : NumberInt(100),
  "Staff" : [
    {
      "StaffId" : NumberInt(1),
      "StaffName" : "John Doe"
    },
    {
      "StaffId" : NumberInt(2),
      "StaffName" : "John Smith"
    },
    {
      "StaffId" : NumberInt(3),
      "StaffName" : "John Jones"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5f11d4c28663f32e940696e1"),
  "PdfId" : NumberInt(110),
  "Staff" : [
    {
      "StaffId" : NumberInt(4),
      "StaffName" : "Bob Loblaw"
    },
    {
      "StaffId" : NumberInt(5),
      "StaffName" : "Edward Nigma"
    },
    {
      "StaffId" : NumberInt(6),
      "StaffName" : "Hugh Mongus"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `Staff` array, change the type of `StaffId` and merge objects with other fields using `$mergeObjects`

```
db.getCollection("staff.roster").update({},
  [{
    $set: {
      Staff: {
        $map: {
          input: "$Staff",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              { StaffId: { $toInt: "$$this.StaffId" } }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6nf3V3xFCpB)

Comment: I ran the query in the playground and in my local copy and while the aggregate result shows the updated information, the database collection itself isn't updating. Is there a step missing?

Comment: where you exciting this query? what response are you getting? and have you verified the fields name with you having in collection.

Comment: I'm executing in the shell, the shell output returns the updated document and array of sub-documents, which have the correctly modified StaffId value, but the parent collection remains un-modified

Comment: I am not sure why its not happening, just verify database name and collection name and mongodb version should be 4.2 or above.

Comment: version 4.2.8 and I have confirmed all of the DB and collection names. It looks like it's just generating an output of the modified information rather than actually applying the changes to the DB

Comment: don't run playground query in your shell, that is just view purpose, use query from my answer. that is `.update(`